# oscilloscope for ubuntu 13.04

Tags: sound, software-recommendation

I need to import an mp3 or an ogg file and analyse it through an oscilloscope. Is there any free (as in beer) software to do so? I am aware of xoscope, but in the internet I have only found tutorials that show how to let it work whenever sounds are imported through the micro. I would like to simply "open" a file and start the analysis. Is there anything that does so in a simple and reliable way?

Comment: What kind of analysis are you to conduct?

Comment: well, "analysis" is probably an exaggeration. mostly, i would like to show to my students what is an overtone, what are partials and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should think that Audacity from the default Ubuntu repositories would be able to do this.

Here's a few things I found: [Spek](http://spek.cc/) (and its GUI, [pulseview](https://sigrok.org/wiki/PulseView)) and [Sonic Visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/) and I also found [this page](http://linux-sound.org/dsp.html), which contains many links to different software for Linux.

Comment: thanks phpdev. unfortunately, in my version of audacity (2.0.1) there is no oscilloscope, but only a spectrogram, and i was not able to find any reasonable plugin to enable an oscilloscope-like visualisation.

Comment: Added more info.